Plaid Sandbox Identity Verification invalid phone number
From the docs on sandbox testing (https://plaid.com/docs/identity-verification/testing/) I'm trying to test the case of Ben Wyatt who fails the doc verification but am getting "user.phone_number must be a valid phone number" error for "+16667778888"
Here's the requested json
{'client_user_id': '2161',
 'gave_consent': False,
 'is_idempotent': True,
 'is_shareable': True,
 'template_id': 'idvtmp_19kzyuHmLVjEsT',
 'user': {'address': {'city': 'Sherman Oaks',
                      'country': 'US',
                      'postal_code': '94123',
                      'region': 'CA',
                      'street': '620 Worster Ave Apt 101'},
          'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1975, 1, 18),
          'id_number': {'type': 'us_ssn', 'value': '111223333'},
          'name': {'family_name': 'Wyatt', 'given_name': 'Ben'},
          'phone_number': '+16667778888'}}

and here's the response
plaid.exceptions.ApiException: Status Code: 400
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Wed, 06 Nov 2024 23:08:39 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '230', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
HTTP response body: {
  "display_message": null,
  "error_code": "INVALID_FIELD",
  "error_message": "user.phone_number must be a valid phone number.",
  "error_type": "INVALID_REQUEST",
  "request_id": "sowlqt49yPHLFhl",
  "suggested_action": null
}


Thanks for bringing this to our attention! It appears that due to a recent update to libphonenumber (which is used by Identity Verification to validate phone number input prior to attempting verification), the phone number for the Ben Wyatt test user no longer works. The team is looking at this issue to replace the phone number for Ben, but for right now, this test user cannot be used. (When Ben's number is updated, I'll edit this answer and leave a comment.)
